# What's the reason of allowing arbitrary labels inside the switch statements?

Tags: c#, language-lawyer

The following code compiles:

```
int a = 0;

switch (a)
{
    case 1:
        return;
    defau1t:      // note the typo
        return;
}
```

because `defau1t` is interpreted as a [`goto`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx) label.

However in the following case:

```
switch (a)
{
    defau1t:
        return;
}
```

the compiler correctly identifies the mistake:

> error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `defau1t', expecting`}', `case', or`default:'

Why is that? What's the reason of allowing arbitrary labels inside the `switch` statements if it leads to (seemingly) incoherent behaviour?

*Side note*: The same problem can be observed for similar snippets for C++ and Java.

Comment: Is there anywhere that labels are *not* allowed?  I don't think somebody specifically decided to allow labels in switch.

Comment: I guess there is really no sane way to *disallow* labels inside `switch` without making special "*switch_only_statement*" in addition to regular "*statement*"

Comment: `goto` would be rather pointless if you couldn't have labels, wouldn't it?

Comment: The label defau1t: is not a 'switch' label. It is a 'goto' label. It's perfectly legal to have goto statements inside a switch. The second switch has no 'switch' labels and thus not legal.

Comment: @Dennis_E: A switch statement can be legal without any switch labels (as long as the switch block is empty).

Comment: @mellamokb In four places: file scope, namespace scope, and class and struct definition scopes.

Comment: @Dennis_E I can see that, as noted in the question. My point was why the language allows unreadable and confusing code where for example it has features that disallow case fall-through.

Comment: @BartoszKP I understand what you're saying, but unreadable and confusing code is something you need to try to avoid yourself, too. The language designers would have to have a good reason to disallow one particular corner case.

Comment: @Dennis_E Good point. I was just very surprised to see this :)

Comment: Note that the provided code does produce two warnings. One about unreachable code and another about an unreferenced label. While an error might preferable, if my code is not working as I expect, warnings are one of the first things I look for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're looking at this the wrong way. It's not that a special exception has been made to allow it, it's that no special exception has been made to disallow it.

There is a rule that a `switch` block must start with a `case` or `default` label, but other than that, any valid code can be part of the block.

Including other labels.

Disallowing this would make the language more complicated to understand, would make compilers more difficult to write, and would have some benefit, that benefit is only minor.

Comment: Seems you accurately read my mind. I did think about `switch` blocks as something special, with a predefined structure of cases and inner case blocks. Your perspective clears this up. I'd still argue whether this is all right - there is an inconsistency: fall-through is disallowed because it can be confusing, so some *additional special rules exist* for the sake of code readability. Seems that this is the same case.

Comment: @BartoszKP Fall-through is indeed disallowed. That's not a special exception in the syntax, though. The previous `case` branch doesn't need to end with `break;`: it might also end with an "infinite" loop (possibly with an inner `return` statement), or a `return` statement directly, or a `goto`, or a `throw`, or anything else that doesn't actually cause any fall-through. The compiler checks when it sees the `case` whether there is any way to reach that `case` other than from the `switch`. I don't see how that could be extended to check for ordinary labels without rejecting valid useful code.

Answer (score 1):

C# works this way because this is what is in the specification. Section 8.7.2 of the C# specification defines the grammar of a switch statement. Notably, if the switch block is not empty, it must contain a switch section, and a switch section must start with a switch label, which is `case <constant expression>:` or `default:`. In your second example, you have a non-empty switch-block which does not contain a valid switch section and is thus not a valid statement.

To channel Eric Lippert a bit, disallowing labeled statements within a switch block is a language feature that would need to be conceived of, proposed, designed, specified, developed, tested,  documented, and shipped. My guess is that this feature probably never made it past being conceived of.

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, 1) most languages "work" in their way because that's how they were made, and because of their grammar. 2) every language feature needs to be conceived, proposed, designed, specified, developed, tested, documented and shipped. Both of these statements apply to virtually anything in programming context, so they don't seem very helpful.

Comment: @BartoszKP: The fact that your question admits an unhelpful answer is a function of the vague question. Ask a more precise question if you want a better answer.

Comment: The only answer to "why does this language not have feature X" is "because feature X is not in the spec". The only answer to "why is feature X not in the spec" is that feature X did not make it past one of these steps in the design & implementation of the language. If you're asking "why didn't feature X make it through these steps", then any answer you get from anyone not on the language design team is going to be pure speculation.

Comment: @EricLippert hvd's answer seems fine to me.

Comment: @RyanM The question is not "why does this language have feature X" but what's the reason of behind it. If I understand correctly, that's what the tag language-lawyer is for.

Comment: @BartoszKP: The accepted answer begins by saying that the question is based on fallacious reasoning, rejects the question, and answers the less-vague question that you didn't ask.

Comment: The accepted answer says, in the first paragraph, that this is a feature that was not implemented. In the second paragraph, it indirectly references the language spec. In the third paragraph, it speculates on why the feature wasn't added. At the root, it doesn't seem terribly different from my answer, honestly.

Comment: @EricLippert True, that I could tweak the question more towards: "why it does not have a feature of disallowing labels in switch, when it doesn't allow fall-through". But seems it wouldn't attract any better answer (unless you could provide some constructive insight into this). Still, your diagnosis seems a bit exaggerated.

Comment: @BartoszKP: You make a reasonable point. I have a bias against "why does the compiler not do X" questions; I get them *all the time* and they are very difficult to answer satisfactorily.

Comment: @RyanM I admit that what you indicate are valid similarities. But it starts from a different point, and I found it more helpful. Just wanted to provide some feedback, why I didn't accept your answer. Take it or leave it.

Comment: @EricLippert Sorry to hear that. Fortunately, here questions are not addressed to anyone in particular, and you are not forced to answer :)

Comment: @BartoszKP: Sure, I'll take it. I'd admit that I've been reading Eric for years now and his bias against this type of question has rubbed off on me. I think you should agree though, that the question as stated could only be answered authoritatively by someone who was part of the decision not to implement the feature (now that Eric's here, I guess that's not 100% out of the question). Reading the `language-lawyer` tag description, I don't think it's intended for "why" questions, which is good because they're mostly impossible to answer.